# ¿Como cambiar el formato de fecha de excel a año-mes-dia?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Un gran gran saludo! , quisiera saber como se puede formatear la fecha de excel ya que tengo de forma predeterminada de esta forma ej: 12-03-2022 , y quiero que este así 2022-03-12, para luego poder hacer una importación de ese excel a base de datos , y no me toma el primer formato a si que intento cambiarlo a el segundo formato,(trabajo con mysql y php), intente cambiarlo en excel de esta forma :
[image: Cambio]

Le doy a finalizar para cambiar el formato pero no se me produce ningun cambio en el excel, de antemano muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues basándome en la documentación, puedes convertir tu fecha aplicándolo desde el formato de celda. Por ejemplo, supongamos que yo tengo esta fecha `(dd/MM/yyyy)` y quiero que sea `(yyyy-MM-dd):`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar `**ctrl+1**` veremos el formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, solo queda buscar el `formato` que se nos apetece ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presionamos **aceptar y listo**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Me funciono! , aunque lo intente en formato csv, me hace el cambio pero al guardar y cerrar se queda con el formato anterior y no se guarda, sabes porque se produce esto?

Comment: Te hago una consulta, al momento de guardar el archivo, ¿Te sale así CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (.csv).? Y además, ¿Te figura la opción "Mantener el formato actual"?

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo! , igualmente gracias por el apoyo!, se hacia el cambio en el csv pero no de forma visual , cuando hice la inserción de datos a una base de datos se me produjo el cambio de formato !

Comment: Buenísimo, me abreve.  Recuerda marcar como correcta (en caso de que te haya servido) la respuesta para que se cierre la pregunta